# how to pass params to action#new (in a nested has_many association) via link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, link-to

I have a cinema system where you can select a session and buy a ticket for that
so I have a link_to:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Buy', new_offer_path(:session_id => session.id) %></td>
```

I have a model called offer and a model ticket, when the user press Buy it generates a Offer. this offer has a nested Ticket and the info that i need is the session_ID to create a ticket id in the offer.

Here is my offer controller `#new` action:

```
def new
    @offer = Offer.new
    @offer.ticket = params[:session_id]

    respond_with(@offer)
end
```

but it wont work, i need the params i have passed by link to fill the ticket fields in the offer how i do that?

other maybe usefull

*Offer* model

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :ticket
end
```

*Ticket* model

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :session
  belongs_to :seat

  has_many :offers
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following in your form:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :session_id, :value => params[:session_id] %>
```

So that the `session_id` persists till the `create` action.

Comment: Thxx, i think this gonna work, i cant test this right now but, when i test i tell and accept this answer